# What are the conditions for getting a MVP award after a battle?

Tags: final-fantasy-tactics-a2

In *Final Fantasy Tactics A2*, after a battle there is a chance for one of your characters that participated to get a MVP award.

[image: MVP Award After Battle]

The MVP status seems to fill up a "trophy" bar next to their stats on the character menu:

[image: Character Status Screen]

When the MVP bar fills up it looks like this:

[image: Full MVP Bar]

According to the instruction booklet, the higher a character's MVP bar is, the better they perform on Dispatch missions.

It seems it's possible for two characters to each get a MVP award after a battle (happens rarely) or none at all.

My Jugglers get MVP awards often by just using the "Smile Toss" ability (Target takes next turn) often in a battle, but it doesn't seem to happen when my Thieves use their Steal abilities. If one of my characters deal a lot of damage in a battle they get can get a MVP award, but only if they are not the ones ones doing damage or if they do at least certain amount of damage.

**What are the conditions for a character to be awarded MVP after a battle?**

Comment: This is just pure speculation, but I've acted under the assumption that every action awards so many MVP points during a battle (different actions grant a different amount of points). Whoever has the most MVP points at the end is granted MVP (which could account for why multiple units can be awarded MVP). Th

Comment: @Wipqozn I've tested it out and it seems that the bar accrues a total of 20 points, with the scarf and the circle being the final and minday points, respectively. You character has to actually get the MVP award for it to fill up the bar. I'm curious to see if accuring a certain amount of Smash Points has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that you need to have accrued at least 50 Smash Points on a character in order for it to be eligible for the MVP award after battle.

You get 10 Smash Points each time an ability hits (hostile or friendly), up to a total of 100 points. Scion summons (once you have the appropriate accessories) cost 30 smash points.

The character unit with the most points at the end of the battle is awarded the MVP status.

Comment: do you gain more smash points if your ability hits more than 1 target?  Also, do reflex skills generate smash points?

Comment: I believe it only applies to active abilities, including using an item. AOE abilities only count as one hit I believe, unless it misses all targets, then none.

Comment: 1 more question, is it net or gross smash points?  If I gain 50 points and then use a scion, am I still eligible for the mvp?

Comment: I believe it is gross, otherwise multiple MVPs would appear more often. Although the gauge caps at 100, I believe Smash Points accumulated is still being counted.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up, I was always wondering how it determined a certain character was mvp (like you usually it was my juggler)